# I have a issue with the url in nodejs

Tags: node.js, url

I am creating a small application and I have a problem, in my homepage I have this url localhost:8000/ this is my home so, when a put a name of some other page like localhost:8000/test it will direct to this page and this is not good, I have to create some method to avoid this kind of thing,what I want is just that when I put any name after localhost:8000/ it redirect to itself and show some message like "You can't access this page".

Comment: We can only really help you if you show us the node.js code you have for handling your routes.  Questions about code must include the relevant code.

Comment: aah I'm sorry I'm new here, I'll make some adjustments and send it to you. thanks :)

Comment: You can use the "edit" link below your question to modify it and add the relevant code.